# Does $f(x)=x$ have continuous restriction on any compact set of $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Does $f(x)=x$ have continuous restriction on any compact set of $R^n$

I think it does. Take $\delta=\epsilon$... Just wandering if this kind of proof is sufficient?

Comment: State clearly what you want..... restriction of a continuous function is continuous

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [the restriction of a continuous map is continuous](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Continuous_Mapping_is_Continuous).